# How to apply styling to MapView when using @arcgis/core for imports?

Tags: reactjs, arcgis-js-api

In my React application I'm rendering a MapView. However, the zoom in/out button along with any popup templates are appended below the map in standard html.

[image]

When I previously used esri-loader for importing arcgis modules, I could fix this issue by setting a CSS option to true, like so. The styling would match the [API examples](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/display-a-map/).

```
loadModules(["esri/views/MapView"], {css: true})
```

But I can't find any instance of a CSS or styling property in the MapView class. So how do I apply this styling when using @arcgis/core for imports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation recommends [importing directly from the cdn](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/es-modules/#configure-css):

```
@import "https://js.arcgis.com/4.20/@arcgis/core/assets/esri/themes/dark/main.css";
```

Or if you want to import it from your local, you can follow [their instructions](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/es-modules/#managing-assets-locally) for referencing local assets, and import from your node_modules:

```
@import "@arcgis/core/assets/esri/themes/dark/main.css";
```

Comment: Thanks. I use create-react-app and adding import '@arcgis/core/assets/esri/themes/dark/main.css' to the top of my index.js fixed the issue!